# Redirection to microsoft teams app from browser

Tags: javascript, angular, window.location

I'm working on angular project and I have a teams icon in .html. I need to redirect from browser to the teams app when the icon is clicked. Similar functionality is implemented for mail and phone number. When a user clicks on phone icon or mail icon, I'm doing this:

```
window.location.href = 'tel: 456****';
windo.location.href = 'mailto: example@gmail.com'
```

Tried for a while to know what should be assigned to window.location.href so that the redirection happens to teams app and didn't find any way for it. How do I redirect to teams using window location?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the official documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#deep-linking-to-an-audio-or-audio-video-call

There's examples for both if you have an email address and if you have a phone number. (You'll need that `4:` part before the phone number.)

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users={emailaddress}
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=4:{phonenumber}
```